# Upgrading from 1.6.0 to 1.7.1 removed the box shadow and other css

Tags: leaflet

I was using Leaflet version 1.6.0. I am using ruler and other controllers on the bottom right of the map. They have box shadow and small in size. Refer to the following to see how it looks witrh V1.6.0

[image: V1.6.0]

Now, today I updated the leaflet to V1.7.1. When I compiled my code I noticed that some CSS styles are removed from my controllers. Refer to the following.

[image: V1.7.1]

As you can see the box shadow is gone and size is also changed.
I want to understand the cause of it.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to [this change in the detection of browser touchscreen capabilities](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/commit/0ae68f4658cb1cd85e6e0c67a24b12e5e6282e22#diff-5c529ba8a005e494ea6280599f5e7a70576a7544ec825327efc4c77f2213c5fd) in [pull request #7029](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/7029):

```
- // @property touch: Boolean
+ // @property touchNative: Boolean
  // `true` for all browsers supporting [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Touch_events).
- // This does not necessarily mean that the browser is running in a computer with
+ // **This does not necessarily mean** that the browser is running in a computer with
  // a touchscreen, it only means that the browser is capable of understanding
  // touch events.
- export var touch = !window.L_NO_TOUCH && (pointer || 'ontouchstart' in window ||
-       (window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof window.DocumentTouch));
export var touchNative = 'ontouchstart' in window || !!window.TouchEvent;

+ // @property touch: Boolean
+ // `true` for all browsers supporting either [touch](#browser-touch) or [pointer](#browser-pointer) events.
+ // Note: pointer events will be preferred (if available), and processed for all `touch*` listeners.
+ export var touch = !window.L_NO_TOUCH && (touchNative || pointer);
```

Whether a web brorwser supports touchscreens or not [impacts the CSS classes applied to the Leaflet map container](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/ab9c909ecfbc330e3346b571860a584d92662dae/src/map/Map.js#L1104-L1109):

```js
        DomUtil.addClass(container, 'leaflet-container' +
            (Browser.touch ? ' leaflet-touch' : '')
```

...which in turn impacts the [CSS rules applied to the controls](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/ab9c909ecfbc330e3346b571860a584d92662dae/dist/leaflet.css#L452-L456), e.g.

```css
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-attribution,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar {
    box-shadow: none;
    }
```

The logic in Leaflet 1.6.x does not detect touchscreen capabilities in your web browser, but the logic in 1.7.x does. The CSS rules just follow that.